# Matching Joint Actuator Input Dimensions with PID Controller Output Dimensions [Drake]

Tags: drake

I am trying to wire a PID controller's output to the input of a Joint Actuator. For context (pun intended), I'm able to wire together the continuous state output port of my platform model, which is just a revolute joint, to the PID controller's input because the dimensions are both size 2. I think I'm conceptually misunderstanding something about the actual data types my ports return. Here's a picture of my diagram context and the associated code:

[Diagram context visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuNwQ.png)

[Code screenshot pt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHXEE.png)

[Code screenshot pt 2 with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Q52.png)

[Plant context pt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmhWR.png)

[Plant context pt 2 with some more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUp5J.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated! The error is in the commented-out line 58 of screenshot 2. The dimensions of controller.get_out_port_control() = 1 (which makes sense), but the dimensions of the input to the actuation input port must be 2 (which I don't understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing the sdf files, but when you parse an SDF, you will automatically get a joint actuator for any joint that does not have an `effort limit = 0`.  I suspect that you are getting another actuator that way?

Comment: Ah that's exactly the issue! I actually had two actuators instead of one because I did not set effort limit = 0. Thank you!

Comment: I solved my issue by adding effort limit = 0 in the SDF and then manually adding an actuator named "shoulder_actuator" in the multibody plant. I didn't know how to access the name of the actuator when the actuator was automatically generated, so manually adding the actuator let me define the name I wanted.